# How did Soma contract pulmonary consumption?

Tags: puranas, soma

It says that after Soma was born he developed tuberculosis. Was it literal tubercolosis was it just a part of his inability to do certain things a certain way?

Comment: Physically as Soma (Moon) it is manifested as waning and waxing of moon.. To the Moon God itself it is related to curse of Daksha who gave curse to Moon God saying his body will Kshaya (decay) and since tuberculosis is also called Kshayaroga the curse is often associated with tuberculosis...